# How to know <root of the kernel source tree>

Tags: linux, kernel

In https://github.com/facebook/flashcache/ there is a saying

> `make KERNEL_TREE=<root of the kernel source tree>`
>
> This builds both the flashcache.ko and 3 utilities.
>
> flascache-sa-guide.txt has details on how to create and load
>   flashcache volumes.
>
> Mohan Srinivasan Paul Saab

What should I wrote to replace ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### CentOS

Reference: [Tutorial Link](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/I_need_the_Kernel_Source)

Quick quote from tutorial:

Step 1: As normal user

```
[user@host]$ mkdir -p ~/rpmbuild/{BUILD,BUILDROOT,RPMS,SOURCES,SPECS,SRPMS}
[user@host]$ echo '%_topdir %(echo $HOME)/rpmbuild' > ~/.rpmmacros
```

Step 2: As root

```
[root@host]# yum install rpm-build redhat-rpm-config asciidoc hmaccalc
[root@host]# yum install binutils-devel elfutils-libelf-devel newt-devel zlib-devel
```

Step 3: As normal user

```
[user@host]$ rpm -i http://vault.centos.org/6.3/updates/Source/SPackages/kernel-2.6.32-279.19.1.el6.src.rpm 2>&1 | grep -v mock
```

kernel source tree: `/home/user/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel*/linux*/` <-- cd into it to confirm those '*'.

So

```
make KERNEL_TREE=<put in the full path above>
```

### Debian

`<root of the kernel source tree>` is where the kernel source is.

On Ubuntut/Debain, download kernel source

```
apt-get install linux-source-3.2.0
```

That will put the kernel source tree in

```
/usr/src/linux-source-3.2.0
```

However the actual source tree need to be de-compressed

```
# cd /usr/src/linux-source-3.2.0
# ls -lh
total 77M
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4.0K Jan 24 22:40 debian
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4.0K Jan 24 22:40 debian.master
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  77M Jan  8 17:46 linux-source-3.2.0.tar.bz2

# tar xf linux-source-3.2.0.tar.bz2
# ls -lh
total 77M
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4.0K Jan 24 22:40 debian
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4.0K Jan 24 22:40 debian.master
drwxrwxr-x 24 root root 4.0K Jan  8 17:45 linux-source-3.2.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  77M Jan  8 17:46 linux-source-3.2.0.tar.bz2
```

The source tree is `/usr/src/linux-source-3.2.0/linux-source-3.2.0`

So

```
make KERNEL_TREE=/usr/src/linux-source-3.2.0/linux-source-3.2.0
```

Comment: How should I know my kernel_source tree?

Comment: I used centos how do I know where the kernel source is?

Comment: What is the output of `uname -a`?

Comment: root@host [/]# uname -a
Linux host.hostgreatsite.com 2.6.32-279.19.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Dec 19 07:05:20 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: ok, that look like standard kernel, wait.

Comment: ok, updated for centos

Answer (score 2):

The Red Hat, CentOS, and Fedora systems have the `kernel-devel` package, containing the machinery required to build modules against the kernel (not the full source, mind you). The source's root is then at `/usr/src/kernels/<version>`.

Answer (score 2):

To compile extra kernel modules, you usually need to install the package with the header files for your kernel called

- `kernel-devel` on RedHat-based distros (Fedora,CentOS,...)
- `linux-headers-$(uname -r)` on Debian-based distros (Ubuntu, ...).

In `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/`, there should be then a symlink `build` 
which should point to the right directory.

So install the kernel header package and then use

```
make KERNEL_TREE=/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build
```

Comment: This is good advice for 99% of kernel modules. Note that flashcache is in that other 1% - building it requires the full source tree.